# PHP PDO + PostgreSQL - transactions handling

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, transactions

I have a problem that I cannot find appropriate answer to in the available sources.

**Problem description**
When I call postgres function from php using PDO, I do not receive response (ajax call is waiting) and as a result I get timeout. There is no problem with parameters paaasing. Function is working fine when I run it directly in postgres as a transaction:

```
begin;
select lcp_mess_ordering(1);
fetch all po_cursor;
commit;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Code details:

**PHP part**

```
try {
$conn = pdoDbConnect();
$conn->beginTransaction();

$query = 'select lcp_mess_ordering(
            pi_msg_id := :post_pi_msg_id
        )';

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam('post_pi_msg_id', $_POST['msg_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);   
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();                            

$stmt->closeCursor();
$conn->commit();
unset($stmt);
(...)
```

**PostgreSQL function**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lcp_mess_ordering(IN pi_msg_id integer, OUT po_cursor    refcursor, OUT po_err_num integer, OUT po_err_desc text)
RETURNS record AS
$BODY$  
DECLARE
v_proc_name text;
v_step integer;
v_next_step integer;
v_msg_id integer;
v_message_row record;
v_max_step integer;
mess_cursor cursor for select "MSG_ID", "MSG_STEP" from lct_messages_tmp where "MSG_AUDIT_RD" is null;

BEGIN
(...)

select "MSG_STEP" into v_step from tbr_messages where "MSG_ID" = pi_msg_id;
select max("MSG_STEP") into v_max_step from tbr_messages where "MSG_AUDIT_RD" is null;

for v_msg_id in select "MSG_ID" from tbr_messages where "MSG_STEP" = v_step
loop
    select "MSG_NEXT_STEP" into v_next_step from tbr_messages where "MSG_ID" = v_msg_id;
    IF v_next_step = (v_step + 1) THEN
        update tbr_messages set
        "MSG_NEXT_STEP" = null,
        "MSG_AUDIT_MD" = now()
        where "MSG_ID" = v_msg_id;
    END IF;
end loop;

update tbr_messages set
"MSG_STEP" = (v_step + 1),
"MSG_AUDIT_MD" = now()
where "MSG_STEP" = v_step;

open mess_cursor;
loop
    fetch mess_cursor into v_message_row;
    exit when not found;
    IF v_message_row."MSG_STEP" = v_step + 1 THEN
        update tbr_messages set
        "MSG_STEP" = v_step,
        "MSG_AUDIT_MD" = now()
        where "MSG_ID" = v_message_row."MSG_ID";
    END IF;
end loop;

OPEN po_cursor FOR 
(...)
RETURN;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN others THEN 
    po_err_num := SQLSTATE;
    po_err_desc := SQLERRM;
    RETURN;



END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Comment: Where is your ajax code then ?

Answer (score 0):

Missing ajax part:

```
$('body').on('click', '#down_btn', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();


    var msg_id = $(this).attr('data-msg_id');


    var request = $.ajax({      
        url: '../admin_php/mess_move_down.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: { 'msg_id': msg_id },
        dataType: "html",
    });

    request.done(function( data ) {
        $( '#assigned_section' ).html( data );
    });


});
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with place where

```
$conn->commit();
```

was located in the code.

Worth reading: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php